# Reactjs-onClick event not firing the first time i click button

Tags: reactjs

i had a problem , when i first click my button is not firing , but on the second click is working , any help ? i dont understand why this happen

```
    render() {
    return (
    <button type="button" className="basic-submit-button"  onClick={this.submitUsernameChange}>{window.main.resources["SaveChangesButton"]}</button>
    );
}

submitUsernameChange() {
    if (this.canSubmit()) {
        PersonalInfoActions.changeUsername(this.state.newUsername);
        HeaderActions.logout();
        this.setState({ submitting: false });
    }
}
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.submitUsernameChange = this.submitUsernameChange.bind(this);
    this.state = PersonalInfoStore.getState();
}
```

Comment: `this.canSubmit()`, can you show this method

Comment: canSubmit() {
  return this.refs.newUsername.isValid();
 }
i tried to debug  it , but on the first click it not enter the submitUserNameChange method

Comment: can you create a reproducible codesandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: i think i cannot , is a very large complex project with a lot of files  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone got this type of error ,  i fixed changing the handlerBur to onKeyPressUp event . seems that the events where overlaping .

Answer (score 0):

You should check if newUsername is valid before allowing the form to submit. You could disable the submit button and check if the username is valid on type.

Comment: yeah on the full js file already validate that , the real problem is that it doesnt go to the submitUserNameChange method on the first click , already tried to debug it.