# onClick event not working on first click in react

Tags: reactjs

In here when i press the search button the first time the 'username' state doesn't recieve any data. The 'username' state is empty and the API request in the App.js fails. The second time i click the same button everything works as expected. How do i make it work on the first click ? What's wrong here?

```
const Search = ({setInputText, setUsername, inputText, username}) => {

    const inputHandler = (e)=> {
        setInputText(e.target.value)
    }

    const searchHandler = (e)=> {
        e.preventDefault()
        setUsername(inputText)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input value={inputText} onChange={inputHandler} type="text"/>
                <button onClick={searchHandler}>Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

EDIT : ADDING App.js here

```
function App() {

  //States
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("")
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
  const [stats, setStats] = useState([])

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>Game Stats</h1>
        <Search setInputText={setInputText} setUsername={setUsername} inputText={inputText} username={username} setStats={setStats}/>
        <Stats stats={stats}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You design of component doesn't seem right.  Post the the parent component so that we can share some effective feedback as the usage of the props setInputText, setUsername, inputText, username in the parent component is not clear.

Comment: Added the app.js code please review.

Comment: suggestion => <button onClick={searchHandler} disabled={inputText}>Search</button>

Comment: I copied your code into codesandbox but couldn't reproduce your error. Clicking search or hitting enter key updates username
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-pare-zcfo6?file=/src/Search.js

Comment: what could possibly be wrong here if i did everything correct?

Comment: okay so there might be a little confusion because of the code i posted. i wanted the 'console.log(username)' to be in the searchHandler function because that's where i'll be performing an API call. The state is set on button click i but i can''t access it on the first click.

Comment: Why can't you use the inputText to make the api call in your searchHandle?

Comment: because i want to clear search input box after every click by doing setInputText("") inside searchHandler

Comment: Also if i was to just get the input text after a button click. How would i do so inside searchHandler?

Comment: How do you check `username` current state at your code?

Comment: by adding a console.log(username) right after setUsername(inputText) inside searchHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me helped something like `<button onClick={(e) => searchHandler(e)}>Search</button>` after I read [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54827991/13891817)

> seems that the events where overlaping

Answer (score 3):

So first you should use a callback like so :

```
onClick={(e)=>searchHandler(e)}
```

If you have **handleBlur** in your input element please remove because these states usually interfere so the button wont update on first click but on second.
Had the same problem myself and this resolved it.

Comment: There are times where you can't just pass a function name (if it's a method or if you want to change what arguments it receives) but in this case, your function to call a function is not necessary and the original code was fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the following and move `searchHandler` as the value of `onSubmit` in the `<form>` tag

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => searchHandler(e)}>
  <input value={inputText} onChange={inputHandler} type="text"/>
  <button type="submit"> Search </button>
</form>
```

More on https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Did you use handleFormSubmit(e) or searchHandler(e) within onSubmit? What error do you get?

Comment: Yeah used searchHandler and there is literally no error in that. The username state doesn't get updated on the first click and thats it.

Answer (score -1):

If your component is inside ScrollView component, and you come across this behavior, add this `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}` to the ScrollView.